# Use uncanonized name in FOS User Bundle symfony2

Tags: symfony

I can use canonized name in confirmation email for example with %username% email with %email%, etc.
But how can i use not canonized name in it?
I see no way how can i do it.

Comment: What do you mean by *canonized*? (english is not my mother tongue)

Answer (score 0):

Nope. With `username` and `email` you get the uncanonical name/email. With `usernameCanonical` and `emailCanonical` you get the canonical version.

Respective the methods in php:

```
$user->getUsername();
$user->getUsernameCanonical();
$user->getEmail();
$user->getEmailCanonical();
```

Comment: I have FOSUserBundle.yml config file, something like:

[code]
registration:
    confirmed: Congratulations %username%, your account confirmed.
[/code]

%username% is canonized version of user name (lowercase). Is any way i can use uncanonized user name in such config files?
I don't want lowercase username in confirmation email.

Answer (score 0):

I got how to do it.

FOSUserBundle has templates for registration confirmation page, etc.

There is line like that:
[code]

{{ 'registration.confirmed'|trans({'%username%': user.username}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}

[/code]

All you need is to change it to:

[code]

{{ 'registration.confirmed'|trans({'%username%': user.fullname}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}

[/code]

Where fullname is some property which contains uncanonical username